# Chain Mapper in Hadoop 3.2.0

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to map multiple Mappers in my program. But am not able to use ChainMapper in Hadoop 3.2.0 version.

Here is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.Data.Maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>Hadoop</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
         <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
         <version>2.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>
</project>
```

And here is my import statment and showing error  `The import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain cannot be` 
     resolved

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.ChainMapper
```

May I know please what am missing here ..? Why am not able to use ChainMapper ..? In which version I can find it ..?

Thanks

Comment: Why is your hadoop-core dependency version 1.2.1 instead of 3.2.0? That's almost certainly to blame.

Comment: @CharlieFlowers, But latest available version hadoop-core is 1.2.1 ..! https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core

Comment: You don't need that. You're a client, so you want client core https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core